# How to list variables given equation?

Tags: expression-manipulation

Given an expression, is there any means to list variables?

Example:

a^3 + b^2 + c -> a,b,c

I need this functionality because I am manipulating large expressions of many variables (20) and would like to know which variables remain once the manipulations have been done.

Comment: Do you have parameters in those expressions ?

Comment: @Sektor, I am new to Mathematica. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Variables` command:

```
 Variables[a x^2 + b x + c]
```

(*
{a,b,c,x}
*)

You can easily remove the `x`.

Alternatively:

```
CoefficientList[a x^2 + b x + c, x]
```

(*
{a, b, c}
*)

Answer (score 4):

A quite general approach is to use `Cases`.

```
Cases[a^3 + b^2 + c, z_Symbol :> z, {0, Infinity}]
(* {a, b, c} *)
```

or

```
Cases[Cos[a] b^c Gamma[d]/e, z_Symbol :> z, {0, Infinity}]
(* {b, c, e, a, d} *)
```